# How to create directory like urls for each page on a website

Tags: php, apache, web

I have a content site that spreads across multiple pages but there is only 1 index.php file which retrieves the data from the database based on the page no.

Currently the url direction has to be something like `domainname.com/Page/content.php?page=3`

I have noticed, quite a few sites have directory like structure for the urls like:

`domainname.com/Page/3`

I know how to change it to `domainname.com/Page/?page=3` but I am looking to remove the `?page` part.

How can I do this, without individually creating a directory for each page, the content keeps growing, hence changes for each page.

Thanks

Comment: htaccess url rewriting is what you need. Check this http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html discussion about converting http://www.example.com/viewcatalog.asp?category=hats&prodID=53 to http://www.example.com/catalog/hats/53/ this is what you need too Something useful http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html

Comment: What is asked for here is also know under the term http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL

Answer (score 4):

These sites use mod_rewrite to do a "rewrite" on the requested URL using a regular expression

EDIT:

rewriting this: `domainname.com/Page/3`

to that: `domainname.com/Page/content.php?page=3`

would look like this in the `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/(.*)$ /content.php/$1/page=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /error_with_mod_rewrite.html
</IfModule>
```

here i also made a restriction for the var name to be a letter either capital or small.

Answer (score 0):

"URL Rewrites" is the feature that performs a custom URL structure.   This is a very common and important feature in most common web servers.  URL rewrites are not just available with Apache.  For example,

Apache uses the Mod_Rewrite Module.

Nginx uses the 'Rewrite' and "Try_Files" directives.

Cherokee has the feature built-in, configurable from admin web panel.

there are many more examples, these are just some I have worked with.  In addition, I have heard some projects do the rewrites in the programming code.  This has become more prevalent with the new language specific web-servers.